# tkinter Combobox insertion resulting in max 2 rows and encased in curly brackets for top row

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox, xlrd

I have a method which checks the sheet in xls and based on the option chosen by the user in combobox 1, populates the combobox 2 filling it with information from the xls sheets. The issue is the combobox 2 is only properly showing the second row and all previous rows are combined in a weird way encased in curly brackets.

The method:

```
def retrieve():
    print(monthchoosen.get()) #test
    print("domain chosen ", monthchoosen.get())#test 2
    if monthchoosen.get() == "sheet1":
        print("True") #Test 3
        sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
        sheet.cell_value(0, 0)
        for i in range(sheet.nrows):
            print ("x") #test4
            projectchosen['values'] = ('test', projectchosen['values'], sheet.cell_value(i,0))
    elif monthchoosen.get() == 'sheet2':
        sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(1)
        sheet.cell_value(0, 0)
        for i in range(sheet.nrows):
            print(i) #test5
            projectchosen['values'] = (projectchosen['values'], sheet.cell_value(i,0))
```

The output:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please provide a runnable [mre].

Comment: The values includes a list as one of its elements. All values need to be strings.